# Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE does not inject Model and Request to @Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

The code below was working fine with Spring 4.2.6.REALESE. Now, after migration something was changed and I started to get nulls in my @Controller Is it a bug?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/client")
public class ClientController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String test(Model model) { 
    // model is null at this point
    return "client/test";
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller class code?

Comment: Nothing special like in the answer below, just a simple controller, I do not have any aspects like Transactional or Validated but I use PreAuthorize. Maybe this can be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: 4.3.0.RELEASE requires Servlet 3.0+

Longer proof:

Model is null because a method to find a proper `ArgumentResolver` for `org.springframework.ui.Model` finds the first one on the list which is `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver`
instead of `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelMethodProcessor`

That is the invalid part of code form HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite

```
private HandlerMethodArgumentResolver getArgumentResolver(MethodParameter parameter) {
    HandlerMethodArgumentResolver result = this.argumentResolverCache.get(parameter);
    if (result == null) {
        for (HandlerMethodArgumentResolver methodArgumentResolver : this.argumentResolvers) {
            if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                logger.trace("Testing if argument resolver [" + methodArgumentResolver + "] supports [" +
                        parameter.getGenericParameterType() + "]");
            }
            if (methodArgumentResolver.supportsParameter(parameter)) {
                result = methodArgumentResolver;
                this.argumentResolverCache.put(parameter, result);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver is here first on the list and its
`RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter)` returns true because of this line:

```
if (MultipartResolutionDelegate.isMultipartArgument(parameter)) {
                return true;
            }
```

and then in `MultipartResolutionDelegate`:

```
public static boolean isMultipartArgument(MethodParameter parameter) {
    Class<?> paramType = parameter.getNestedParameterType();
    return (MultipartFile.class == paramType || isMultipartFileCollection(parameter) ||
            isMultipartFileArray(parameter) || servletPartClass == paramType ||
            isPartCollection(parameter) || isPartArray(parameter));
}
```

isPartCollection returns true because of this strange comparison where both sides of the equation are nulls !!

```
private static boolean isPartCollection(MethodParameter methodParam) {
    return (servletPartClass == getCollectionParameterType(methodParam));
}
```

servletPartClass is null because of this

```
private static Class<?> servletPartClass = null;

    static {
        try {
            servletPartClass = ClassUtils.forName("javax.servlet.http.Part",
                    MultipartResolutionDelegate.class.getClassLoader());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // Servlet 3.0 javax.servlet.http.Part type not available -
            // Part references simply not supported then.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I share your experience with the model object being null. The code below worked well prior 4.3.0-RELEASE. Maybe we are missing some new configuration?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/pricelists")
public class PriceListsController  {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index(final Model model) {
        // Model is null in 4.3.0-RELEASE.
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: if you still looking for an answer, check the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

This [is fixed](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14358) in **4.3.1**

> Spring Framework / [SPR-14358](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14358)
>   Failure to resolve @RequestMapping method arguments in Servlet 2.5 environments